# How do I remove a list of words from a paragraph?

Tags: python

I want to remove a list of words from a paragraph. So I created the list I want remove

```
fitlerWords= ['Cage','Contract','Number','Quantity','Unit','Cost','AWD','Date','CONTINUED',
 'SECTION', 'Procurement','history','For','on','Next','Page','Continuation','Sheet',
'Reference','of','Document','Being','CONTINUED','pages','SECTION']
```

I want to remove the words above from this sentence if they exist

`015536159/6630     CAGE Contract Number Quantity Unit Cost AWD Date 32YK1 SPE2DH19P0522 22.000 1394.13000 20190102 32YK1 SPE2DH18P1630 21.000 1356.41000 20180604 74YZ3  SPE2DH18P1184 15.000 1282.50000 20180314 32YK1 SPE2DH17V1630 16.000 1335.91000 20170214 58837 SPE2DH16V2501 17.000 1369.00000 20160601 32YK1 SPE2DH16M0463 13.000 1358.20000 20151125  CONTINUED ON NEXT PAGE

                                       CONTINUATION SHEET     REFERENCE NO. OF DOCUMENT BEING CONTINUED: SPE2DH-19-T-6601     PAGE 4 OF 22 PAGES        SECTION A  Procurement History for NSN/FSC:015536159/6630  CAGE Contract Number  Quantity Unit Cost AWD Date              32YK1 S$ DH16M0068 32YK1 SPE2DH14V3122 32YK1 S$ DH14V2252 32YK1 SPE2DH14V0165     58837 SPM2DH13V1222 08576 SPM2DH13M0509 58837 SPM2DH12V0342 08576 SPM2DH12M0490 08576 SPM2DH11V1261 3BSP4 SPM2DSO8MA800 3BSP4 SPM2DS08M6542 3BSP4 SPM2DS08M5128 3BSP4 SPM2DS08M5127 3BSP4 SPM2DS08M5125  18.000 1462.05000 20151005 12.000 1246.39000 20140918 9.000 1246.39000 20140711 10.000 1246.39000 20131223 12.000 1258.00000 20130724 15.000 1100.09000 20121205 27.000 1200.00000 20111223 34.000 1057.77000 20111202 3.000 1057.77000 20110727  2.000 947.16000 20080721 100.000 947.16000 20080323 2.000 947.16000 20080227 2.000 947.16000 20080227 2.000 947.16000 20080225  CONTINUED ON NEXT PAGE

                                                                                              CONTINUATION SHEET REFERENCE NO. OF DOCUMENT BEING CONTINUED:  SPE2DH-19-T-6601        PAGE 5 OF 22 PAGES        SECTION B`

so I used this code

```
for x in fitlerWords:
    try:
        filteredHistory = history.replace(x,"")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, x)

    print(filteredHistory)
```

when I print, I get the paragraph. No has been removed. What am I doing wrongly? How can I filter all those words from the paragraph if they exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `re.sub` with an alternation containing all your keywords:

```
fitlerWords = ['Cage','Contract','Number','Quantity','Unit','Cost','AWD','Date','CONTINUED', 'SECTION', 'Procurement','history','For','on','Next','Page','Continuation','Sheet','Reference','of','Document','Being','CONTINUED','pages','SECTION']
regex = r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(filterWords) + r')\b'
filteredHistory = re.sub(regex, '', history, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(filteredHistory)
```

Note: Depending on what your aesthetics are for the replaced history text, you may wish to also remove surrounding whitespace on one side, say the right, of each keyword.  In that case, we can try:

```
regex = r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(filterWords) + r')\s*\b'
filteredHistory = re.sub(regex, '', history, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

The regex logic here builds a pattern looking something like:

```
\b(?:Cage|Contract|Number|Quantity)\b
```

It would of course have more keywords in it, but this is the general pattern.  We use `re.sub` to match on this pattern, and then replace with empty string, to effectively remove all matching keywords.  The `re.IGNORECASE` flag makes this regex replacement regardless of the case of the keywords.

Comment: could you please explain the code, so that i can understand whats going on

Answer (score 3):

To fix your approach:

```py
filteredHistory = history
for filterWord in fitlerWords:
    filteredHistory = filteredHistory.replace(filterWord, "")
print(filteredHistory)
```